# Updating a text file with minimum rewrites

Tags: c++, file, std

In short what is the proper way of updating a file in C or C++ which does the minimum number of write operations necessary.

The longer question:

1. Say I need to update a file by adding information to the end of it. I don't need to load the entire file into memory, I just need to append after the end pointer until the end of the filesystem block (and/or reserve another one). What would be the correct C++ or C standard function to do so.
2. Say I also need to replace a byte array of that file with a byte array of the same length. (e.g. change one ASCII character to another ASCII character). How can I achieve that.
3. Is there a library that **does what I mean** (dwim), i.e. if it needs to insert a byte  array `a[]` of length `l` at a position `p`, that it *overwrites* the `l` bytes after the pointer, with `a[]` then it takes the original bytes at the pointer `p` writes until the end of the file, and then simply appends the last l bytes of the file to account for the new length.

Comment: Appending to the end of the file is easy - just open in append mode. Overwriting existing bytes is easy - just seek and write. *Inserting* into a file by using a couple of temporary memory buffers for swapping contents is a bit unsafe if things go wrong, so most programs create a new file and replace the old file with the new file.

Comment: Have you take a look at `mmap` and `mremap` ?

Comment: Please pick one language. Which are you actually using?

Comment: FYI, on Stack Overflow it is recommended that you only ask one question per post. Also, requests for library recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow so your last question is off-topic. But anyway, don't really need a special library for something so basic. The standard `open`, `lseek` and `write` functions (or their stream counterparts) are all that is needed. You can write a wrapper yourself in a few lines of code.

Comment: I'm lazy and usually just `popen()` an `ed` session to send editing commands to and let it do all the work.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, I'm using C++, but I do need to minimise the number of writes, so if the answer is "there's no such thing in C++" I'd be more than happy to use a low-level C function and adapt it to OOP.

Comment: @Ôrel, AFAIK, mmap is implementation dependent. On GNU it does what I need, but it just happens to overwrite the file in busybox.

Comment: Ok; as that would still be a valid C++ solution I think you ought to remove the C tags to focus your question